# Regular expression required for string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to solve below problem using regular expression. My input string is something like this

```
"MTSGNN0002(  1), MTSGNN0028( 645), MTSGNN0050(  10)"
```

and I want output like this

```
"MTSGNN0002,MTSGNN0028,MTSGNN0050"
```

It should delete all charecter which comes between brackets. Kindly help me out in solving this.

Comment: show your efforts first

Comment: First i was trying with this one `s.gsub(/[(\d\s)]/,"").strip` ,but this was deleting all numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's simpler to find what you want than delete what you don't:

```
s = "MTSGNN0002( 1), MTSGNN0028( 645), MTSGNN0050( 10)" 
s.scan(/MT\w+/).join(',')   # Change MT to whatever suits your data.
```

Comment: I would have said: s.scan(/[A-Z]\w+/).join(',')  in case the 'MT' nomenclature changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this regexp:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\(.*\)
```

http://rubular.com/r/maZNs0mDkv

From there on it's easy ;-)

Comment: +1 for suggesting rubular

Comment: This was just a lucky coincidence :-D I was looking for some way to test a ruby regexp without writing a file.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..

```
\([^\)]*\)|\s
```

As per your question.. The above replaces the brackets and the text inside and remove the spaces.

[Example and Source Demo:](http://rubular.com/r/oQ37XhpJEn)

Answer (score 1):

Here i have got one more solution

```
([(\b]\s.[0-9]*\b\))
```

http://rubular.com/r/9NyoU3RKUT

Answer (score 0):

replace mathes of this regex `\([ \d]+\)` with empty string